# Kitten keeps throwing up and clear liquid keeps coming out of her butt

Tags: cats, health, diet

My sister fed my kitten cereal milk and now she keeps throwing up milk and oozing out clear liquid or goo out her butt and she's drooling a lot. What should I do?

Comment: Hi welcome to Pets, how old is your kitten? I guess it could be diarrhea; cats should never be fed milk, only kittens up to a few weeks should and it must be cat's milk.

Comment: @lila she is about 7 or 8 weeks old im not for sure.

Comment: never give cow milk to kittens,goat milk can be used as a substitute for cat milk but only in an emergency if the kitten gets little or no milk from the mother.